# Only one app on a galaxy tab?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a client that want to have us develop an app that will be the only one running on the tablet.

The goal is to have the app launched on start-up and be the only one VISIBLE by the user.
Then the user will be able to launch a browser by clicking on an icon.

I imagine that i should create a Home replacement app for that purpose. However i would like to know if there is another simplier method?

*Important:* The app is not supposed to be installed from the market and we'll be in charge of installing all the device.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your application as a Luncher application.

here is an example [source](http://code.google.com/p/android-launcher-plus)

Comment: Haven't been able to catch long press on it for some reason. i'm overriding the public boolean dispatchKeyEvent (KeyEvent event) method of the activity. what i'm i doing wrong? on the other hand i would to know how to debug a home replacement application...

Answer (score 0):

Home replacement is the way to go, I cannot think of any other way.

Comment: Actually, i've been successfully doing this so far.
However, the user is still able to launch another app by holding the Home button.

Comment: Can't you catch a long press on the Home button??!